# Constructing Postnikov base functor from Brown-like representability

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

I am looking through the paper "On the Representability of Homotopy Functors" by Heller. At the start of Section 4, he considers the homotopy category $H(n)$ of $n$-truncated pointed connected CW complexes for each $1 \leq n \leq \infty$ and the functor
$$i_{n,m} : H(n) \to H(m)$$
induced by inclusion for all $n \leq m \leq \infty$. This preserves products and weak pullbacks.

Each $i_{n,m}$ has a left adjoint $b_{n,m}$, called a Postnikov base functor. Heller briefly  mentions that the existence of $b_{n,m}$ follows easily from an earlier theorem of the paper, an abstract Brown representability result.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $C$ be a category with small products and weak pullbacks. Suppose that it has a set $S$ of objects $X$ such that the functors $C(-, X)$ jointly detect isomorphisms in $C$. Also suppose that for any large regular cardinal $\kappa$ and diagram $G : \kappa^{\text{op}} \to C$, there is a weak limit $L$ of $G$ in $C$ such that the functor $C(-,Y)$ takes $L$ to a colimit for all $Y \in S$. Then a functor $F : C \to \mathbf{Set}$ is representable iff it preserves products and weak pullbacks.

It seems to me that you want to apply Theorem 1 to show that $$\mathsf{Hom}_{H(m)}(d, i_{n,m}(-)) : H(n) \to \mathbf{Set}$$ is representable for all $d \in H(m)$. This requires knowing that $H(n)$ has a suitable generating set $S$. But I believe there is no such set for $H(n)$ (basically proved by Heller in the same paper). So I do not see how Theorem 1 applies.

I must be missing something here. How does Theorem 1 give us the left adjoints?

Comment: @KevinArlin I thought that's a generating set for $H(n)^{\text{op}}$. My issue is that things don't hold for the covariant case. (I had in mind Heller's counterexample to covariant Brown Rep. for $H(\infty)$.)

Comment: Ugh, I always hated how Heller stated that theorem in the opposite of the way it is applied. I agree that $H(n)$ probably doesn't have a cogenerating set. This paper is a bit fast and loose in general, so it's possible that the claim should be ignored.